# Symfony display all characters in output

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am passing to my partial a form instance and an additional object. What I want is to display to the end user entered content preserving such simbols as **\r \n \t** etc. How can I achieve that? Tried to get raw values of the form or object, but no luck.

inputed text:

```
    test is what I need.   Some stuff like this shouldnt happen at all
------------------------------------------------------------------
Okay\t          Test\r\n
1132\t          123\r\n
```

The problem with spaces is obvious, but how to preserve the example structure is the question.

Comment: Can you add some code you use? And also the output you expect and the output you get. I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: updated the question, please see given example

Comment: What about some code? How do you collect the input and how exactly do you try to display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Wrapping the raw output in a `<pre>` tag helped in my case